# On C# naming conventions for member variables

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have seen an advice somewhere here on SO to not name `private/public` member variables, in a way that they differ only by the case of the very first character. For instance:

```
private string logFileName;

public string LogFileName
{
    get
    {
        return logFilename
    ....
```

and:    `private System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu mainMenu;`

and:    `DialogResult dialogResult = this.saveConfigFileDialog.ShowDialog();`

and:

```
public Version Version
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

and:

```
    private void CheckPollingType(PollingType pollingType)
    {
```

So, did I hear wrong? Is there anything wrong with these naming conventions? If yes, then what are better ways of doing it? Links, references are a plus.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question because the framework design guidelines naming conventions are intended for public and protected members, not private members. They don't really say what to do with private and internal members.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That is definitely a very popular naming convention and I don't see why you should be against it.

I would simply recommend following the [Naming conventions for C# provided by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) and also [General Naming Conventions provided by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

Specifically they have this to say about properties:

> Do name properties using a noun, noun
>   phrase, or an adjective.
>
> Noun phrases or adjectives are
>   appropriate for properties because
>   properties hold data.
>
> Do not use properties that match the
>   names of Get methods.
>
> For example do not name a property
>   EmployeeRecord and also name a method
>   GetEmployeeRecord. Developers will not
>   know which member to use to accomplish
>   their programming task.
>
> Do name Boolean properties with an
>   affirmative phrase (CanSeek instead of
>   CantSeek). Optionally, you can also
>   prefix Boolean properties with Is,
>   Can, or Has, but only where it adds
>   value.
>
> Consider giving a property the same
>   name as its type.
>
> When you have a property that is
>   strongly typed to an enumeration, the
>   name of the property can be the same
>   as the name of the enumeration. For
>   example, if you have an enumeration
>   named CacheLevel, a property that
>   returns one of its values can also be
>   named CacheLevel.

I think if there were a compelling reason to be against what you are suggesting they would have mentioned it in their guidelines.

Comment: The C# naming conventions provided by MSDN are indeed very sensible, but I believe they are only intended for public and protected members. This questions asks about naming conventions for private members, which the conventions don't address.

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek: Personally I would use mostly the same conventions for private as I do for protected but I do fully understand the difference.

Comment: I agree, and I do use the same conventions for private members; however, I have to supply my own rules for how to differentiate for visibility. Linking to the MSDN conventions is not really sufficient to answer this question because the conventions specifically don't cover visibility, which is what this question is really about.

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek: This question is really about if it is a BAD idea or not to use capital for property and non capital for the variable members. I don't think he cares really whether the members were protected or private specifically exactly.  For the purpose of this question he could have equally asked public/protected.  Although that is an insightful observation that you made I don't think it's the pivotal point of this question.

Answer (score 21):

Most of the time class level variables are prepended with an underscore.  So myVariable is actually _myVariable.  A lot of people don't like varrying the name by one character, because it is too easy to make a mistake.

There is nothing wrong with just doing myVariable and MyVariable.  It's just a convention, and if everyone follows it then it will probably work just fine.

Personally if at all possible I dispense with the private variable and just use the getters and setters in the property. Most of the time (but not all the time), accessing the private variable was used to to not allow write access in the property.
This can be solved by:

```
public String MyVariable
{
   get;
   private set;
}
```

Comment: I love `private set/get`, but as you mentioned, this is not always possible. StyleCop does not like underscores.

Answer (score 12):

Typically, I always see private members with a leading _.  (assuming it's not an auto property)

```
private string _customerName;
public string CustomerName
{
    get{return _customerName;}
    set{_customerName = value;}
}
```

Of course, the final verdict is the convention of your team (assuming you aren't doing a lone wolf project or working with utter morons)

Comment: Not so much private members, but private members that correspond with a public one.

Answer (score 8):

I will throw my hat in the ring with what I have always used

```
class ClassName //Classes are PascalCase
{
    public ClassName(int myProperty) //Constructor arguments are named the same as the property they set but use camelCase.
    {
       _myProperty = myPropriety;
    }
    public void MyFunction(object varToBePassed) //Function names are PascalCase, passed pramaters are camelCase.
    {
        int sampleVar; //local variables are camelCase
    }
    public int MyProperty { get { return _myProperty; } } // Properties are PascalCase

    private int _myProperty; // Private fields are camelCase and start with a _
```

Comment: You mean "Property". Propriety is the concept being questioned by the OP in this thread.

Comment: @Heliac I fixed my spelling

Comment: sample var in lowercase is `samplevar`. `sampleVar` is camel case.

Comment: Any suggestions for class-wide variables? I'm coming from VB.NET to C# and having to pick up on this. In VB, I tend to use an "m" prefis, eg `Private msStringValue as String, Private mbFlag as Boolean, Private moThing as Thing`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the definitive guidline from Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)

[I would also recommend this book if you are at all interested in the details and reasons behind the naming and style conventions used across the .NET framework.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

Enjoy!

Comment: I believe these rules are only intended for public (and protected) members. This questions asks about private members.

Answer (score 3):

the main issue with same name with different case, is that not all languages in .net are case sensitive i.e. visual basic.

The only scenario where that's a real issue is when you are exposing public members that only vary by case. There is a compatibility attribute one can set so the compiler tells you if you have one of such scenarios.

Above said, this doesn't really affect the scenario of the backing private member.

Answer (score 2):

No there is nothing wrong with these naming conventions.

The property version is actually the recomended format according to the .Net framework design guidelines.

The field declaration likewise conforms to the framework guidelines as it's camelCased.  It's occasionally a bit of a religous war as to whether or not the variable should be prefixed with a `_` or `m_`.  That's a question that needs to be resolved within your group though.

.Net framework design guidelines for type members

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx

Answer (score 2):

One reason I can think to not use case to differentiate public vs private members is that Visual Studio Intellisense will sort both members right next to each other, so you might use the wrong one without noticing.

That being said, I use the convention you described (using case to differentiate accessibility) in my code, and I haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 2):

The two most popular conventions I see are prefixing private member variables with either a _ or m_. 
I personally prefer the m_ convention, but as long as it's consistent across the project/team, I really don't care. I'm not one to get into 'religious wars' :)

Answer (score 1):

What ever naming convention you do choose - be consistent. Then at least when you come back to the code in six months time, or when someone new looks at it for the first time, they'll be able to work out what's what.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of this scenario though:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int Foo { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(int foo) {
        // oops, setting the parameter to itself, not the property
        foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio will warn you about this situation, but it's not illegal and can slip through sometimes.

Comment: Always using "this." to access members alleviates this problem and makes it easier to identify members vs locally scoped things.

Comment: That requires you and your entire team to remember that convention. I also think it's a rather ugly convention, using "this" too much really pollutes the code.

Generally I prefer member variables to start with underscores, and granted "this" solves this problem whereas the underscores do not.

Comment: Good point, both of you. Stylecop forces this. Problem is - some projects did not start to use StyleCop right away, and still generate thousands of warnings.

Comment: @Matt Greer: Part of the reason I prefer using "this." is that it puts the scope information in a different "band" than the member name. If all members have the same prefix, it is harder to find the a specific member using IntelliSense.

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek I agree, that would alleviate this problem however seeing this.xyz is horribly bulky to look at IMHO.  I don't know that it is worth it.

Comment: @joshlrogers, I prefer seeing `this.xyz` rather than `MyClassName.ABC` used inside the class. If within the class I need to treat members and static stuff differently, I would prefer `this.` any day.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem with the naming convention proposed is Intellisense will use the private variable over the property.  In many cases that's not actually a problem (is, in fact, usually a good thing), but for those few cases where it is, a convention that separates the two names is useful.  I like m_ for private member variables and c_ for private static variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing C# it's no problem, but if you (or your team/company) are also doing VB.Net (which is case insensitive), then I'd recommend that it might be better to not do this in C# either so that the naming conventions between different languages don't differ too much.

Answer (score 0):

Since this pops up among the topmost search results regarding the topic I wanted to share my suggestion, too:

In addition to the Pascal/camelCase convention for public/private members, I always choose member variable names which consist of **2 or more words**, and local variable names which consist of a **single lowercase word** or even just a letter.

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas {
    public int CanvasId { get; private set; }
    private double canvasHeight; // member vars consist of 2+ words
    private double canvasWidth;

    public MyCanvas(int id) {
        CanvasId = id;
        double height = ...; // local vars consist of one word/letter
        canvasHeight = height;
    }
}
```

This allows to choose consistent and meaningful variable names, without 'funny' prefixes like `_`, but also to distinguish between local and member variables.

Comment: this stops working when in a `ComputeDimensions(someParameters)` body you need to calculate also (e.g.) member field `pictureHeight` and "borderHeight`

Comment: anyway, it's quite strange that there is quite a general agreement on naming Properties and Methods (CamelCase), local variable and parameters (camelCase), but not on member variables (camelCase as you suggest, _camelCase, mCamelCase, m_CamelCase, and so on...)